# mIRC Script snippet misfirigin

Tags: mirc

Whenever somebody just types ! point the snippet runs through all of its commands for some reason I'm trying to find what causes this to happen, so far I cannot find the issue in the code

```
 alias -l sd { return " $+ $scriptdir $+ $$1 $+ " }
    on $*:text:/^!(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|website|food|touchy|sakura|Bass|bacon|snickers|bot|quiz|quizrules|NYE|NYD|stop|dance|Leta|back|sways|ladies|enters|choice|lounge|hiphop|fault|country|piano|rocks|diva|diva1|hello|sassy|hips|bounces|woot|kiss|pops|wiggle|greets|gotit|phone|next|cheeky|dj|xmas|here|guitar|twist|dj1|facebook|cheeky1|jig|birthday|thanks|chacha|moves|fleshies|aerial|drinks|heifer|dances|tap|chacha1|jam|hairbrush|hairbrush1|hairbrush2|reggae|lmfao|accept|hairbrush3|touch|no|music|tinbot|buffering|fleshie1|brat|2step|twirls|vote|whistle|hohey|scripted|botgurl|shows|phone1|laughs|me|crazy|shares|rani|takes|hour|mj|elvis|profiles|song|sweet|brightie|fire|passenger|lr|)$/Si:#:{
      if (!%f) { inc -u6 %f
        if ($isfile($sd(timetable.txt))) { .play $+(-t,$regml(1)) # $sd(timetable.txt) 50 }
        else { msg # Either timetable.txt doesn't exist or the txt file name doesn't match! }     
      }
    }

    menu * {
      Ping-Pong:$iif(%pp,pingpongoff,pingpongon)
      Anti-Idle:$iif(%antiidle,antioff,antion)
    }
    on 1:ping: { $iif(%pp,raw pong $1 wannaplaypingpong,) }
    on 1:pong: { $iif(%pp,raw ping $1 wannaplaypingpong,) }
    alias pingpongoff { unset %pp | echo -a Ping-Pong has been disabled. }
    alias pingpongon { set %pp on | echo -a Ping-Pong has been enabled. }
    alias antioff { timeridle off | unset %antiidle | echo -a Anti-Idle has been disabled. }
    alias antion { .timeridle 0 120 scid -atM1 antiidle | set %antiidle on | echo -a Anti-Idle has been enabled. }
    alias antiidle { .msg $status $me }
    raw 401:*: {
      if (connected isin $1-) && (%antiidle) { echo -s ***** SassIRC Anti-Idle | halt }
    }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error at the end of your regex.

```
...fire|passenger|lr|)$..
```

Which contain redundant last pipe `|`, remove it from the end and it will solve the problem.

Comment: Good eyes I honestly didn't see that when I was looking at it